# Firefox 52: Javascript parseFloat not working with UTF-16 strings

Tags: javascript, firefox, utf-8, parsefloat

I have been trying to read the contents of a UTF-16 file in Firefox v52 with this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "downloads/dg_mare_piwik_social.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {

        // Split the lines

        var lines = data.split('\n');
        for (var i = 1, len = lines.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var items = lines[i].split(',');
            console.log(items[0], Number.parseFloat(items[1]));
        }
});
```

The problem is that in the console I get `NaN` from the `parseFloat(items[1])`.
This happens only in Firefox, all other browsers get the number with that.

How can I get it to work? How can I get the number from a UTF-16 string?

Comment: Whats the raw value of `items[1]`?

Comment: The problem isn't at the JavaScript layer, it's before it gets to JavaScript. Most likely, the file is encoded one way (say, UTF-16) but the server response says it's encoded another way (say, UTF-8), and so the data is corrupted by the time it gets to JavaScript.

Comment: And note that by the time you're dealing with a JavaScript string, [it's always UTF-16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-string-value) (but with invalid surrogate pairs allowed), regardless of how it started out.

Comment: The raw value for items[1] is plain numbers, but using the method I mentioned above I get it in firefox with some strange character between the digits of the numbers and NaN when trying to convert the string to number.

But T.J. you were correct. The file that has been generated with php fwrite is UTF-16. Adding this has solved the problem:

beforeSend: function (data) { data.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=UTF-16'); },

Thank you so much,
Nikos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to T.J. Crowder that helped me to identify the source of the problem. Changing it to this has solved my problem:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "downloads/dg_mare_piwik_social.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    beforeSend: function (data) { data.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=UTF-16'); },
    success: function(data) {

        // Split the lines

        var lines = data.split('\n');
        for (var i = 1, len = lines.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var items = lines[i].split(',');
            console.log(items[0], Number.parseFloat(items[1]));
        }
});
```

Adding the overrideMimeType at beforesend.